# Codeigniter: this->datatables->select(sample)->from(sample)->where()

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

Please help me. i can not use my dataTable properly. what I want to do is

`select from table and use the`where`function`. but i cant do it properly.

here is my controller code

```
 public function reporttable ()
    {

        $zz = array('empnumber' => $this->input->post('empnumber'));
        //$this->db->order_by("surname", "asc");
         $this->datatables->select('date_auto,particulars,earned_VL,aul_VL,balance_VL,aulx_VL,earned_SL,aul_SL,balance_SL,aulx_SL,date_leave,action_taken')
        ->from('tblreport')->where($zz);

        echo $this->datatables->generate();
    }
```

this is my supposed query:

> select * from tblreport where empnumber = (the empnumber in my textbox.)

there, i get a value from a textbox to my view. but it didn't work. i know that is wrong. can you please help me with my problem? thank you.

```
<p align="center"> <?php echo $this->table->generate();?></p></div>
<?php foreach ($tblemployee as $row){?> 
<input type="text" name="empnumber" readonly="readonly"  value="<?php echo $row->empnumber;?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="empnumber" value="<?php echo $row->empnumber;?>"/>
```

here is my view for guide. thank you.

Comment: Please check this [link](http://www.ahmed-samy.com/php-codeigniter-full-featrued-jquery-datatables-part-1/) it will help you

Comment: thank you for the answer. i checked it a while ago before i asked. i cant find the answer there. but thank you for your answer.

Comment: @jbnaron -  if you want i can give another code for handling datatable.

Comment: @Bugfixer how to do it mate?

Comment: @jbnaron- Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/y9nrkjzc/1/) buddy

Answer (score 2):

as Simple you can use

In **Controller**

```
$data['tblemployee'] = $this->model_name->reporttable($id)//assign your data base value to variable 
$this->load->view('your view name',$data )
```

in **Model**

```
public function reporttable($id)
    {
    $query = $this->db->query("select * from tblreport where empnumber = '$id'");
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result; // this will return your data as array
}
```

In **view**

```
<?php 
foreach ($tblemployee as $row)
{
echo $row['id];

}?>
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. i know your point but what am i saying is i want to select something from my table where my empnumber is equal to the id i want. it is a query for dataTable. thank you for your answer.

Comment: you need to just pass data from URL and its automatically do above codes

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

To make it more simplier.

In model :

```
public function reporttable ($id){

  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('tblreport');
  $this->db->where('empnumber', $id);

  $query =  $this->db->get();
  return $query->return_array(); // use this if so want to return many query if not you can also use first_row('array')
}
```

In controller :

```
public function function_name (){
  $data['variable_name'] =  $this->model_name->reporttable($id); // change the model_name by your own model where your function reporttable is located and use the variable_name for your view,

  $this->load->view('view_name' , $data); // load the view page you want to display.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Controller**

`$data['tblemployee'] = $this->model_name->reporttable($id)//assign your data base value to variable 
$this->load->view('your view name',$data )`

in **Model**

`public function reporttable($id)
    {
    $query = $this->db->query("select * from tblreport where empnumber = '$id'");
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result; // this will return your data as array
}`

In **view**

`<?php 
foreach ($tblemployee as $row)
{
echo $row['id];

}?>`